# What can be done to mitigate risk to property from large trees other than removal?

Tags: safety, fire-hazard, backyard

There are 3 oak trees that need to be removed as they pose risks
to personal safety and property during windstorm. The last windstorm (dec. 2019, AK) produced 120 m/h gusts. The quote is $6k due to complexity  plus a crane will need to be utilized to accomplish the task. 
Is there anything else could be done?

Comment: In some locations you need permission to fell an oak as they are protected.

Comment: Sounds like a courtyard with building on four sides. Here in the piney woods ( many experts available) , they cut large trees ( 100' by 3 ' diameter) using a boom truck that can reach 50' feet from any roadway or lawn, and lower the pieces of tree by rope.. I have had 10 trees removed . One in the summer cost $600 to cut and remove . It may be worth getting other estimates.

Comment: The one removed in summer was a "baby" ; 100' by only 18" diameter.

Comment: Thank  you all. They estimated it at 5K.

Comment: You're welcome, but please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how this network operates. "Thank you" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit broad since you've provided very little detail about the situation, but hiring an arborist to guide structural pruning would almost entirely eliminate risk of blowdown.

We have large white oaks in our neighborhood, and they're rarely blown completely down, but they do tend to lose large, long, high branches in severe storms. Shortening or removing those would substantially reduce risk. Obviously there's still cost involved, but perhaps quite a bit less, and you get to keep some beautiful trees.

Comment: I have a huge oak at my home we had it pruned by a licensed arborists when we purchased this place 5 years ago. Last year we had a really bad snow storm and we lost a few branches but nothing worth removing the tree, we had the arborists come back and take care of one branch that needed removal and trim a few others he said needed it but the 2nd trip was 450$ the first was a little over 1000 maybe 1200 but we still have our tree I would agree with Isherwood that ti would be less expensive and probably look better to keep the tree with some professional care it made it through the storm.+

Comment: +1 for recommending an arborist. They always want to coat the cut areas with some special protection to keep bugs and moisture out.

Comment: I've been told recently that sealing wounds is no longer advisable, which was news to me. [Here's an article that mentions it](https://s3.wp.wsu.edu/uploads/sites/403/2015/03/wound-sealer.pdf). It's more about knowing where to cut, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could get an engineer to devise a steel collar with steel rope that could prevent the trees from falling in a certain direction.  Depending on the location / size of the trees / structures you could devise something that allows you to retain the trees.

Comment: So guy wires to the ground? Have you seen this done anywhere? I'm curious about the anchoring that would be required. I'd expect that a large concrete structure would be needed.